# set angular button from button list as selected

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to get one of my buttons to be selected, both on init to get one change it's css to selected and second to replace it on click and keep it as selected. Currently when clicking the buttons toggle to selected and return to unselected. In addition I need to keep them as only one selected at a time.

My angular module code:

```
'use strict';
(function () {

class operationBroadComponent {
    constructor() {
        this.buttonsList1 = [
            {title: 'title1', iconDefaultPath: 'icon0 tab enable', iconPressedPath: 'icon0 tab selected'},
            {title: 'title2', iconDefaultPath: 'icon1 tab enable', iconPressedPath: 'icon1 tab selected'},
            {title: 'title3', iconDefaultPath: 'icon2 tab enable', iconPressedPath: 'icon2 tab selected'},
        ]
    }
}

$onInit() {

}

$onChanges(changedObj) {

}

angular.module('myApp')
.component('operationBroad', {
    templateUrl: 'app/windowsComponent/operationBroad/operationBroad.html',
    controller: operationBroadComponent,
    transclude: true,
    bindings: {}
})
.controller('OperationBroadCtrl', function($scope, $http){
    var mybtnList = $scope.$parent.$ctrl.buttonsList1;
});


})();
```

My html code:

```
<div class="operation-broad-container" ng-controller="OperationBroadCtrl">
<div class="col buttons-container">
    <operation-button ng-repeat="button in $ctrl.buttonsList1"
                      title="{{button.title}}"
                      default-img="{{button.iconDefaultPath}}"
                      pressed-img="{{button.iconPressedPath}}">>
    </operation-button>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: what part of this code isn't working as expected?

Comment: It is not that it is not working, I cannot seem to toggle the buttons to selected from the OperationBroadCtrl controller

Comment: Toggle them how? You don't have any code here showing what you are describing at all;  There is no css here, and there doesn't even seem to be a click handler.

Comment: This is exactly what I am asking, What is the way to create a click handler, that will indicate which button was pressed, In addition to set on load a default button index 0 to be pressed.

Comment: well to be honest this code is a bit of a mess;  you have a `controller:` parameter pointing to a class, which makes no sense, and you completely defeat the purpose of using components by doing `$scope.$parent.$ctrl`.  it would be much easier to understand what you are having trouble with if you presented a [mcve] of your issue instead of a list of requirements.